# Resultado para uma consulta Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho esta consulta no Mysql:

```
SELECT 
 usuarios.modalidade, 
 produtos.idproduto,
 produtos.nome,
 produtos.referencia,
 produtos.ean,
 produtos.valorvenda,
 produtos.quantidadeprodutos.minimo,
 tabeladepreco.desconto 
FROM produtos,tabeladepreco INNER JOIN usuarios ON
 tabeladepreco.modalidade = usuarios.modalidade 
WHERE produtos.nome like '%arroz%' AND 
 tabeladepreco.idproduto = produtos.idproduto AND 
 usuarios.modalidade = tabeladepreco.modalidade AND 
 produtos.ativo = 1
```

Onde a minha ideia é trazer todos os produtos com o nome `arroz`, mas se a modalidade da tabela de preço (`tabeladepreco`) for igual a modalidade da tabela `usuários`.
A busca está correta, porém,  a tabela `usuarios` tem mais de mil linhas, e ele vai repetindo os produtos pra cada linha.

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma maneira de ele fazer somente uma vez, só que só tenho a modalidade para comparar com a tabela `usuarios`.

Comment: Seria legal você, ao invés de usar `tabeladepreco.idproduto = produtos.idproduto` no AND, utilizar no INNER JOIN: `FROM produtos INNER JOIN tabeladepreco ON tabeladepreco.idproduto = produtos.idproduto. Remova também a redundância no AND da modalidade.

Comment: Fiz desta maneira @RogersonNazário:
`SELECT produtos.idproduto,produtos.nome,produtos.referencia,produtos.ean,produtos.valorvenda,produtos.quantidade,produtos.minimo,tabeladepreco.desconto FROM produtos INNER JOIN tabeladepreco ON tabeladepreco.idproduto = produtos.idproduto WHERE produtos.nome like '%arroz%' AND produtos.ativo = 1`
Mas ainda assim, repete o resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro aplicar a palavra chave `DISTINCT`, logo a seguir ao `SELECT` de forma a remover as entradas duplicadas.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
  usuarios.modalidade, 
  produtos.idproduto,
  produtos.nome,
  produtos.referencia,
  (...)
```

Comment: Descobri que realmente irei ter que usar mais uma comparação, o id do usuário, pra poder dar certo.
Como tenho uma chamada Java Script para este codigo, vou ver como fazer para enviar mais uma variável para consulta. 
Obrigado pela atenção.